# Python: how to make form a string comprising of text and variable values in python 2.6

Tags: python, string

Basically I'm looking for concatenating the strings and variable together.

In Java:

```
String s = "HI my name is "+var_name+" I'm "+age+" years old";
```

In PHP:

```
$s = "Hi my name is ".$var_name." I'm ".$age." years old";
```

I want a similar thing in Python. I know the format function supported by Python 3.0 and above but I have a constraint of running it at Python version 2.6. I can't upgrade so please tell me the best method.

P.S - I came to know that format works in Python 2.6 also. If you have any other method please let me know that also. It's always good to know more.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this. If you have any other method please let me know that too

Answer (score 3):

`.format` [works on Python 2.6 too](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
"Hi my name is {name}. I'm {age} years old.".format(name="John", age=30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another ways to do what you want:

```
# name is string and age is an integer
"Hi my name is %s. I'm %d years old" % (name, age)
"Hi my name is " + name + ". I'm " + str(age) + " years old"
"Hi my name is %(name)s. I'm %(age)d years old" % {'name':name, 'age':age}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"Hi my name is {0}. I'm {1} years old".format(name, age)
```